# Why I'm not able to comment for this question when other user with 1 rep can comment

Tags: support, comments

In this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/835611/my-computer-doesnt-find-the-bootable-device) already a user with 1 reputation(at the time of asking this question) has commented but when I tried to add comment, its showing "**You must have 50 reputation to comment**". Why am I not able to comment with 13 reputations when user with 1 reputation can comment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comment you see was actually an answer post converted to a comment by a moderator. ♦Moderators can convert answers to comments provided they are no more than 600 characters long. (Perks of being a 10k user—I can see deleted answers most users cannot.)

This typically happens when a user intends to post a comment and cannot do so for the very reason you described: insufficient reputation. The restriction simply exists to protect against spam. Users with less than 50 reputation can still comment on their own questions and their answers.

[image: Screenshot of answer converted to comment]

Comment: Then is it OK to answer for a post to which we want to comment and ask the moderator in that same answer to convert it to comment?

Comment: You really shouldn't do that. Instead, you should post some good-quality answers to other questions and earn the required reputation. I know this can be frustrating, but we wouldn't have such a high-quality, spam-free Q&A experience without these stringent restrictions.

Comment: I also see you have 192 reputation on [ubuntu.se]. You just need two question upvotes or one answer upvote there to get the +100 association bonus on all other sites, including Super User, and this would resolve your problem.

Comment: @learner - No;  You shouldn't create more work for the moderators and everyone in the community by posting an answer that is only a comment.  Get the reputation then post the comment.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the moderator that converted that, and your mileage, as far as comment conversions may vary.

*In general* we prefer that users *not* post answers for conversion, but rather get the necessary reputation to do so. We may, however see a comment that is useful, and rather than outright deletion, choose to convert it. In general, if you know what a comment is/should be, you'd have the rep to post those anyway.

In this case, well, the suggestion was *extremely* useful, and I felt it didn't deserve to be canned. The user didn't flag it for conversion.